# get members who have a role - spatie permission

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question, how do I get users who do not have a role?
I use spatie permission
ex:

```php
User::notRole('manager')->get()
```

Here is a query that performs the required, but the user must have at least one role because it is used whereHas,
otherwise, it will be a result null
If the user doesn't have a role I can't get him among the users who don't have a role manager

```php
    public function scopeDoesntHaveRole(Builder $query, $roles, $guard = null): Builder
    {
        if ($roles instanceof Collection) {
            $roles = $roles->all();
        }
        if (!is_array($roles)) {
            $roles = [$roles];
        }
        $roles = array_map(function ($role) use ($guard) {
            if ($role instanceof Role) {
                return $role;
            }
            $method = is_numeric($role) ? 'findById' : 'findByName';
            return $this->getRoleClass()->{$method}($role, $guard ?: $this->getDefaultGuardName());
        }, Arr::wrap($roles));

        return $query->whereHas('roles', function (Builder $subQuery) use ($roles) {
            $roleClass = $this->getRoleClass();
            $key = (new $roleClass())->getKeyName();
            $subQuery->whereNotIn(config('permission.table_names.roles') . ".$key", \array_column($roles, $key));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach it like this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
 
$users= User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', 'manager');
})->get();
```

since on their documentation they have an example:

```
$users_without_any_roles = User::doesntHave('roles')->get();
```

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage#content-eloquent

Comment: If the user doesn't have a role I can't get him among the users who don't have a role manager